# Jython (JES) - Function for rotating a picture

Tags: image, rotation, jython, jes

I've been stuck on this problem for hours, and I just can't figure it out, or find any similar questions to help me. I have to write a function that takes in a picture and a number, and it rotates that picture left by the number. I found the function to rotate the picture left pretty easily, but I have no idea how I would go about writing it X amount of times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "rotate it by a number" or "X amount of times?" X degrees?

Comment: If you have the code to rotate it left once, can't you just call it in a loop X times, or `X % 4`?